# Is there a problem with the close vote review?

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

Since the down time at the weekend I have noticed that, when reviewing close votes, the vote to close pop-up does not always refer to the question I am about to vote on.

For instance, just now I tried to vote to migrate [how to point a domain (or two) to a primary domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/739176/how-to-point-a-domain-or-two-to-a-primary-domain) but, even though I knew the question already had a vote to migrate, the pop-up showed that someone had voted to close because "Unclear what you are asking".

Closing the pop-up and refreshing the page sorted it out. This happens on both my work and home PCs. 
So. is there a problem with the close vote review system?